# How to create a file on Ubuntu with C File I/O

Tags: c, file, ubuntu

I have a simple question if anyone can answer it. I'm currently starting off with Ubuntu and am learning the environment though I'm use to using Windows. On Windows if I wanted to create and write to a file I would do:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
fclose(fp);
```

When using Ubuntu what should I put in the parameters of fopen(), say I want to have the file created on my desktop. My computer's name is "root1". Sorry if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: This will work as it is on ubuntu. Just make sure that the filename is correct. For eg, if the file you want to operate on is called "xyz.txt" and is located in your home folder, `fopen("/home/your_username/xyz.tzt", "w");` will work.

Comment: Weird this is what I get. "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" Edit: Got it working, thanks brother.

Comment: Check if `fp` is NULL after `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("c:\\test.txt", "w");
if( fp != NULL ){
    fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
    fclose(fp);
} else{
    perror("Could not open the file");
}
```

Error checking should always be done and pointers should not be left uninitialized.

Comment: Is it necessary to initialize it to null, what are the consequences if it is not? This didn't come up when I read online.

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize a pointer, but recommended.

Answer (score 0):

in simple way of u want to take path of any file in Ubuntu then just right click and select properties ...

then it shows path copy it up and  append '/filename.extension' thats it